# Returns 503 service unavailable when uploading files to heroku

Tags: heroku, file-upload, graphql, apollo-server, heroku-ci

Apollo server setup in Heroku and tried to upload files using Altair but it returns 503 service unavailable.

But when uploading files in my local it uploads successfully so I dont know what am i missing.

This is my mutation :

```
mutation($img1: Upload, $img2: Upload){
  uploadDocument(Image1: $img1, Image2: $img2, Type: 1){
    Code
    Message
  }
}
```

The output is 503 service unavailable and this is what I get from the output of altair.

https://prnt.sc/p1z2c1